# Sheet API V4 Save to new row

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to save from my script to google sheet, but it seems to override the same cells over and over again, I think its about the "range"? I tried to put there - "Patients!A1:C" as I saw in some codes but its not working.

How I can save to new row?

```cs
    static string spreadsheetID = "myspredshete";
    static string path = "mypath.";
    static SheetsService sheetsService;

    public static RequestTest Instance;

    List<string> strings; //all A1:A35 first lines in the 

    string currentRangeName;
    int rowsPerIterration = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.LogError("Google Sheets Master performs start");

        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        SetUpCredentials();
        Invoke("PrintCell",2);
        //Invoke("LogPlayerTersting", 2);
        //LogPlayer(); // not sure we should
    }

    void SetUpCredentials() //this must also be done async  
    {
        string fullPath = Application.dataPath + path;

        Stream creds = File.Open(fullPath, FileMode.Open);

        ServiceAccountCredential serviceAccountCredential = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(creds);

        sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = serviceAccountCredential });
    }

    public void LogPlayer(string patientName,string patientJson, string treatmentJson)
    {
        var valueRange = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange();
        var objectList = new List<System.Object>{patientName,patientJson,treatmentJson};

        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { objectList };// // List<System.object> Objects to save in order of columns

        var updateRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetID, "A1:C1");
        updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;

       // var updateResponse = updateRequest.ExecuteAsync();
        var updateResponse = updateRequest.Execute();
        Debug.Log(updateResponse);
    }
```

I tried to create new var as

```
string range = "Patients!A1:C1";
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it from this Update

```
var updateRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetID, "A1:C1");
updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
```

to Append

```
var updateRequest = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, spreadsheetID, range);
updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
```

Comment: Thanks - you'd be surprised how hard this answer is to find online (especially if you are brand new to Google Sheets API). One other note - you also have to change  this line you have: 

```updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;```


to:


```updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;```